# Difference in various Selenium Waits

Tags: java, selenium, wait

What is the difference between Implicitwait,Explicitwait, Fluentwait and Thread.sleep(), i'm always confused about these waits, if any body can explain i would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Implicit Wait**

The implicit wait will tell to the web driver to wait for certain amount of time before it throws a "No Such Element Exception". The default setting is 0. Once we set the time, web driver will wait for that time before throwing an exception. it can be declared globally, so that any code under that declaration wait for that specific amount time before it throws to an exception.
Eg:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Explicit Wait**

The explicit wait is used to tell the Web Driver to wait for certain conditions (Expected Conditions) or the maximum time exceeded before throwing an "ElementNotVisibleException" exception.Once we declare explicit wait we have to use "ExpectedCondtions" or we can configure how frequently we want to check the condition using Fluent Wait. Already there are many expected conditions exist in addition to that, we can also create custom expected conditions

**Thread.sleep()**

These days while implementing we are using Thread.Sleep() generally it is not recommended to use.These are java wait, it will tell the thread to wait for the specific amount of time(the execution will be stopped until the wait time completes)

Hope it will clear your doubts, For more details refer https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit wait -**
It instructs the web driver to wait for some time by poll the DOM. Once you declared implicit wait it will be available for the entire life of web driver instance. By default, the value will be 0.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Explicit Wait -**
It is the custom one. It will be used if we want the execution to wait for some time until some condition achieved.
By default, the value will be 500 ms

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,20);
WebElement aboutMe;
aboutMe= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("about_me")));
```

**Fluent Wait -**
The fluent wait is used to tell the web driver to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which we want to check the condition before throwing an "ElementNotVisibleException" exception.

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(WebDriver reference)
.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(SECONDS))
.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(SECONDS))
.ignoring(Exception.class);
```

**Thread.sleep() -**
is a static method of Thread class so we can use it using class name i.e. Thread. Thread. sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period. sleep() methods accept duration in miliseconds